# search pattern and make new line with it

Tags: awk

input:

```
2:this is a sentence 221j: 54: this another sentence: 4245: again a sentence 3:the last sentence
```

output

```
this is a sentence 221j: 
this another sentence: 
again a sentence 
the last sentence
```

The snipet should search for 1 or 2 or 3 numbers following by ':'. Take all after the ':' until the next pattern and and make a new line with it.

Comment: If you only want to replace `1 or 2 or 3 numbers following by ':'` with `\n` then why is the 4-digit `4245:` becoming `\n` instead of `4\n`?

Comment: And why are you not replacing the leading `2:` with a newline?  It appears that you are merely deleting it.

Comment: sorry 4245: should be 424: - it's a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following awk(tested in GNU awk) too and let me know if this helps you, also this is tested on provided sample Input_file only.

```
awk -v RS='[0-9]+:' 'NF{gsub(/^ |\n/,"");print}'   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
this is a sentence 221j:
this another sentence:
again a sentence
the last sentence
```

**Explanation:**

```
awk -v RS='[0-9]+:' ' ##Setting Record Separator as all the digits together with colon.
NF{                   ##Then checking if line is NOT blank by checking NF(number of fields) are NOT null, if yes then do following.
 gsub(/^ |\n/,"");    ##Globally substituting starting space and new line with NULL in current line.
 print                ##printing the current line.
}
'   Input_file        ##Mentioning the Input_file here.
```

Comment: Note that using RS with more than one character is not supported in standard awk: "If RS contains more than one character, the results are unspecified."  But this is a good approach.

Comment: Personally, I would simplify it to `gawk NF RS='[0-9]+: *'` and worry about  undesirable blank lines, but it's not clear what the OP actually wants.

Comment: Thanks William for encouragement, sure I should add that it was written and tested in GNU awk.

Comment: *not worry*.  I really wish SO allowed comments to be edited for a longer period of time!

Answer (score 2):

**awk** solution:

```
awk -F'[0-9]+:[[:space:]]*' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i) print $i}' inputfile
```

- `-F'[0-9]+:[[:space:]]*'` - complex field separator

---

The output:

```
this is a sentence 221j: 
this another sentence: 
again a sentence 
the last sentence
```

Answer (score 1):

This does what you said you wanted (replace 1, 2, or 3 digits followed by `:`):

```
$ awk '{sub(/[0-9]{1,3}: */,""); gsub(/ *[0-9]{1,3}: */,ORS)}1' file
this is a sentence 221j:
this another sentence: 4
again a sentence
the last sentence
```

If what you REALLY wanted was to replace any integer followed by `:` as indicated by your sample input/output then that'd be:

```
$ awk '{sub(/[0-9]+: */,""); gsub(/ *[0-9]+: */,ORS)}1' file
this is a sentence 221j:
this another sentence:
again a sentence
the last sentence
```

Comment: @RavinderSingh13: It works! Could you plz explain what you did so that I can modify or reuse the snipet next time. Thank you so much!

Comment: Your second solution works! some little explanations would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much

Comment: @achille: Thank you, I have added explanation too now with my code, let me know if any queries on same.